# Replacing String that have multiple commas

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have data like this in the below column

ColA

**a,b,,**|c,d,e,f|**l,m,,**|p,q,r,s

So here I want to remove the complete data seperated by Pipe(|) if it has two consecutive commas ,,.

My output should be,

ColA

c,d,e,f|p,q,r,s

Pls help with the query.

Comment: How do your current efforts look like? You are unlikely to receive a full solution on this site, the purpose is to ask questions related to a specific issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be using `regexp_replace` with the following example

```
SELECT 
 REGEXP_REPLACE('a,b,,|c,d,e,f|l,m,,|p,q,r,s',  --source column
                '.{1,3}(,,\|)',                 --find pattern 
                '',                             --replace with null
                1,                              --start with position number
                0,                              --occurance
               'i')                             --regex match parameter
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer Charles!! Could you please explain me the find pattern. Its bit confusing.

Comment: Be advised the find pattern only works for this exact data set as given by the OP.  It would fail if the consecutive commas did not come before the pipe, or if there were more than 3 characters before the double-comma-pipe.  The original requirements are not detailed enough to know if this find pattern will work for other conditions.  Could the double-comma appear anywhere in the field?  Are there a variable amount of characters in the field?

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach, but more scenarios addressed:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a,b,,|c,d,e,f|l,m,,|p,q,r,s', '^[^|]*,{2,3}[^|]*\|*|\|[^|]*,{2,3}[^|]*' )
FROM dual;
```

Components of the replacement regular expression (seperated by alternation operator)

`^[^|]*,{2,3}[^|]*\|*`   left end or only one entry

or

`\|[^|]*,{2,3}[^|]*`      center  (always take off left pipe)

explanation:

`^` is an anchor for the start of the string

`[^|]` is a non-pipe character

`*` is the 0, n quantifier

`{2,3}` explicit quantifier match of 2 or 3 times

`|` alternation operator (or)